# Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS Chaincode tutorials

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

does anyone know where I can find good tutorials about chaincode development in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link [chaincode with nodeJS](https://fabric-shim.github.io/index.html) . This one is the official documentation.But I would suggest to develop chaincode with Golang. I found that bit intuitive.The learning curve is bit steep but once you learnt its easier to develop , maintain and scalable too.

Comment: NOTE: This link does not include deployment instructions as of 13MAR2019.